# Torah Blessing - הַמְבֹרָךְ or הַמְּבֹרָךְ

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk

In the blessing before the torah reading, some siddurim have הַמְּבֹרָךְ (with a dagesh in the mem) and others have הַמְבֹרָךְ.  Wouldn't the hay hayedia require a dagesh in the mem thus making the vowel a sh'va na and pronounced?  Are mems exempt from this rule?  I've checked a tikkun, several machzorim, and a slew of siddurim and find no consistency.  Art Scroll, for instance, has no dagesh but indicates a sh'va na!

I'm not sure if this discussion is relevant to the current question?
[Hamracheim or Hammerachim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27613/hamracheim-or-hammerachim)

Thanks for your thoughts, kol tuv, and g'mar chatimah tovah.

Comment: It's indeed the same as in the linked question. (Do we need to generalize that question to close this one?)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Ben.